What is the meaning of "two book length accounts" in the following context?

Van Dijk provides two book length accounts of the notion of context.

What is the meaning of "two book length accounts" in this context?

It's easier to understand this if you hyphenate:

two book-length accounts

"book-length" means "as long as a book".
"account" in this context means a description.
So it means two descriptions of context that are each as long as a book.

Wiktionary
defines book-length:

Of a document or composition, as long as a book; i.e. very long or extensive.

Here Van Dijk gives two long descriptions of context each as long as a book.
